# RSS aggregator with related headlines...like Google News

Tags: rss, aggregators

Does anybody know of a script that would allow me to aggregate RSS feeds (and possibly have users submit their own) while also identifying related/similar headlines much like Google News?

I don't care if it's a standalone script or a plugin for something like WordPress or Drupal. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

How about Pligg for user subvmitted headlines,

or for a custom RSS aggregator you might consider CakePHP and one of the many components available for it

http://milesj.me/blog/read/feed-aggregator-released

Comment: Are there any screenshots or demos I could look at?